# Using Multiple repositories or a Generic Repository

Tags: c#, generics

Im doing an MVC 5 App with AutoFac and Automapper, trying to apply Repository Pattern without Unit Of Work (yet).

I have the following IGenericRepository interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository : IGenericReadRepository
{
    void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;

    void Delete<T>(object id) where T : class;

    void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class;

    void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

This is the other interface that just extends read methods:

```
public interface IGenericReadRepository 
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class;

    T GetById<T>(int id) where T : class;
}
```

And these are their concrete classes:

```
public class GenericReadRepository<TContext> : IGenericReadRepository where TContext : ABMContext
{
    #region Fields
    public TContext context;
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public GenericReadRepository(TContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Methods
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        return context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public T GetById<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class GenericRepository<TContext> : GenericReadRepository<TContext>, IGenericRepository where TContext : ABMContext
{
    public GenericRepository(TContext context)
    : base(context){}


    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete<T>(object id) where T : class
    {
        var entity = context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        Delete(entity);
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The idea at one point was to make a Generic Repository, I have 3 tables with not so much columns, the thing is, I came to the conclusion that, I want to `Delete` a specific entity by some property, look at this EF Domain class:

```
public partial class Alumnos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Legajo { get; set; }

    public int Dni { get; set; }

    public int Carrera { get; set; }

    public int Turno { get; set; }

    public virtual Carreras Carreras { get; set; }

    public virtual Turnos Turnos { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can call `Delete<T>(object id) where T : class` but at this point T is not generic it must be an `Alumnos` entity.
What would it be the best approach to make a new interface to modify an `Alumnos`entity. like this?

```
public interface IAlumnoRepository<Alumnos>
{
    void DeleteAlumnoByDni(int dni);
}
```

The thing is, if the generic interface must implement this interface, then it stopped being generic so I reckon that is a no go, the other one is, how can I accomplish to delete a whole entity by a particular column or property?.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I refactored the whole thing, this is my IRepository now (Dont mind the `NotImplementedException`s for now):

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(object id);

    void Update(TEntity entity);

    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    TEntity GetById(object id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> Table { get; }

    IQueryable<TEntity> TableNoTracking { get; }

}
```

Concrete class:

```
    private readonly DbContext _Dbcontext;

    public GenericRepository(
        DbContext dbcontext,
        DbSet dbset
        )
    {
        _Dbcontext = dbcontext;   
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Table => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IQueryable<TEntity> TableNoTracking => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in my controller that needs to receive or send data to this 3 tables looks like this now (Only Fields and Ctor):

```
#region Fields
private readonly IGenericRepository<Alumnos> _AlumnosRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Turnos> _TurnosRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Carreras> _CarrerasRepository;

private readonly IMapping _Mapping;
#endregion

#region Ctor
public Prog_II_ModelFactory(
    IGenericRepository<Alumnos> alumnosRepository,
    IGenericRepository<Turnos> turnosRepository,
    IGenericRepository<Carreras> carrerasRepository,
    IMapping Mapping
    )
{
    _AlumnosRepository = alumnosRepository;
    _TurnosRepository = turnosRepository;
    _CarrerasRepository = carrerasRepository;
    _Mapping = Mapping;
}
#endregion
```

And my services would look like this:

```
public void DeleteAlumnoByDni(object dni)
{
    var alumnoToDelete = from Al in _AlumnosRepository.Table
                where Al.Dni == dni
                select Al).FirstOrDefault();

    Delete(alumnoToDelete);
}
```

Comment: Why do you add the generic constraint `where T : class`? What does it bring you?

Comment: If you are going to do all of that, why not just use an ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework then you dont need Repository Pattern, because this is already implemented in the framework.

Comment: @FCin Nonsense. If you wrap EF by using repositories you can completely replace EF at will and still keep using your repositories. that's the whole point of using repositories

Comment: @Dbl If you use repositories, then you block Entity Framework's functionality. You can also return IQueryable which is pretty much the same as not using Repository Pattern. Later on you have to make joins, so you create `UnitOfWork` which is also already implemented in Entity Framwork and you are left with useless abstraction. Better option is to just create services as abstraction and use them in Controllers with `DI`.

Comment: I agree with @FCin, your `DbContext` is your "`UnitOfWork`", `DbSet` is your "`Repository`". Much better to implement `CQRS` over repository.